# PHP Ajax request with data to PHP file returning data

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, codeigniter

I'm using CodeIgniter MVC.

I have a table of patients with firstname and lastname. When either is clicked, I need the info of the entire row to send to a PHP file containing methods. The method has to get the data from the view. Send it to the model, get the data and send this data back to the view to populate the form.

HTML

```
  echo "<table class='table' id='tblpatienten' border='1'>";
```

jquery

```
$(document).ready( function() {
            $('#tblpatienten').click( function(e){
                alert($(e.target).text());

                /*jQuery.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "home/getpatientdata",
                    datatype: "json",

                }).done(function(result){
                    //alert($(e.target).text());

                    //alert(result.value);
                });
                */
            });
        })
```

Ive been messing around with this for a couple of days now and I cant seem to figure it out.

The PHP file is called home and has several methods

```
public function getpatientdata(){
 }
```

Needs to receive 2 parameters and return all the details of a patient ( phone number , email and such )

Comment: Which form? Is the form to be populated via `ajax` or form is to be updated via `ajax`.? Not clear

Comment: you can use `data:` to send the parameters to the server.

Comment: The form is empty at the time of a click on one of the table rows. I need ( when one of the rows in the table is clicked ) an ajax request to the php file called "home" with the method "getpatientdata" to receive the row that was clicked. I know I need ajax to do this but I can't get the syntax on everything right. From ajax request to PHP file receiving parameters, sending parameters again and receiving them in the ajax request.

Answer (score 0):

```
    function updatePatientForm(name) {

    var patient = name


 $.ajax({
        'url' : '<?php echo base_url()?>/patients/formUpdate',
        data: {patient: patient},
        'type' : 'POST',
        success : function(data){
                $("#theFormTable").html(data);
            }
        });
```

Now you can just create a blank table with theFormTable as the id and whenever you click this it will make an AJAX request and whatever is echoed will be put into the table

EXAMPLE

HTML

```
<table id="theFormTable"></table>
```

Then in the formUpdate function all you have to do is echo something like this

```
'<tr><th>First</th><th>Last</th></tr><tr><td><input type="text" id="first" name="first" value="'. $row->first . '"/></td><td>
    <input type="text" id="last" name="last" value="'. $row->last . '"/></td></tr>'
```

ect. with whatever you want to see on the form. Then each time you click a different patient it will make all these calls. It is late so I may have screwed something small up but the idea should atleast put you in the right track. Make sure you call this function from the click handler and use the e.target.text as the parameter